# If condition if one of two fields is set

Tags: php

I have a form with many fields and some are mandatory when for two mandatory fields just one need to be set to pass the control and execute the query.
The condition has to return true when the following fields are not empty:

1. type_coupon
2. nature_offre
3. end_date

Beside the above, the field villes or departement (*at least one of them*) must be set, I have the following condition which is not working and I don't understand why?

```
if( (empty($_POST['type_coupon']) 
  || empty($_POST['nature_offre']) 
  || empty($_POST['end_date'])) 
  && ( !isset($_POST['departement']) || isset($_POST['villes']))  
      || ( isset($_POST['departement']) && !isset($_POST['villes'])) ))
{
    echo json_encode(array("state" => "KO",
            "message" => "Champs marqués d'une <em>*</em> sont obligatoires <br> Saisir au moins un departement ou une ville",
            "header" => "<i class='fa fa-times-circle-o' style='color:orange'></i> Champs obligatories !",
            "dateUpdt"=> date('d/m/Y'),
            "timeUpdt"=> date("H:i:s")
    ) , 128);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Please let me know based on your code what is desired ouptput?

Comment: my problem is to check if the field villes or departement is set (at least one of these two fields)

Comment: try this:- if( (empty($_POST['type_coupon']) || empty($_POST['nature_offre']) || empty($_POST['end_date'])) && ( isset($_POST['departement']) || isset($_POST['villes'])))). please take care of bracket and let me know

Comment: still not working, the test failed and doesn't check efficiently what I need

Comment: I think the main problem you are going to have is you are using isset and !isset.  Without knowing your form, I'm going to assume both 'department' and 'villes' are going to be set, but one might be empty.  In this case, your condition is always going to fail.  But what if the user submits both values?  Maybe you should just use precedence between 'department' and 'villes' rather than only allowing one to be set.

Comment: remove all other condition (empty) just check by only  isset($_POST['departement']) || isset($_POST['villes']) and see it's working or not?

Comment: yes you right, that's why I didn't succeed to resolve the case. What do you mean by _Maybe you should just use precedence between 'department' and 'villes' rather than only allowing one to be set_

Comment: @anantkumarsingh not working with your test. I mean if I submit the form without any values (villes or departement) it passes the control and send the query.

Comment: Now it clears . you need to put isset($_POST['departement']) && !empty($_POST['departement']) || isset($_POST['villes']) && !empty($_POST['villes'])

Answer (score 1):

Why not simple create an array of required fields then check if their keys are in the array of posted field then alert. See sample below

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   extract($_POST);
   $required = array('type_coupon', 'nature_offre', 'end_date');
   foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
   {
      if(empty($value) && in_array($key,$required))
      {
         echo 'Error';
      }
   }
   if(empty($field_villes) || enpty($departement))
   {
      echo 'Something';
   }
}
```

Hope you understand the function of `extract()` in the code? I hope this helps you. Safe coding!

Comment: because what I don't have a constant array with required fields. My array can be array('type_coupon', 'nature_offre', 'end_date', 'villes'); or array('type_coupon', 'nature_offre', 'end_date', 'departement');

Comment: yes, see my answer below. I am not sure whether is the best way to resolve this case but it works :).

Comment: Cool. Many roads to success. But I think using the array would help you reduce many if..else conditions and many lines of codes too. Success as you code on

Answer (score 0):

To write in a clear way, you may have to think in functions. Define a simple function that returns true or false and call it from your conditional statement.

Another methodology may be used or added to the previous is using `if... elseif` and the assign an error carrier. Hypothetically, it may be something like the following:

```
$error = false;
if (empty($_POST['f1'])){
  $error = true;
}
elseif(empty($_POST['f2'])){
  $error = true;
}
elseif (empty($_POST['vills']) && empty($_POST['department'])){
 // The two fields are empty at the same time
  $error = true
}
else{
// any additional thing for default
}



if (!$error){
  // member false & false return true.
  // Here do waht you want is validation goes fine...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to manage the situation in that way. Maybe I can combine the first approach to use an array for the fixed mandatory fields and a if for the one of two mandatory field.
Hope this could help someone else.

```
$mandatory_filelds=true;
if( (!isset($_POST['departement']) && !isset($_POST['villes']))  ){
    //echo 'on of two is set';
    $mandatory_filelds=false;
}

if( (empty($_POST['type_coupon']) || empty($_POST['nature_offre'])
    || empty($_POST['end_date']) || empty($_POST['start_date'])
    || empty($_POST['condition_coupon']) || empty($_POST['description']) 
    || empty($_POST['categories']))
    ){
    $mandatory_filelds=false;
}

if(!$mandatory_filelds)
{
    echo json_encode(array("state" => "KO",
            "message" => "Champs marqués d'une <em>*</em> sont obligatoires <br> Saisir au moins un departement ou une ville",
            "header" => "<i class='fa fa-times-circle-o' style='color:orange'></i> Champs obligatories !",
            "dateUpdt"=> date('d/m/Y'),
            "timeUpdt"=> date("H:i:s")
    ) , 128);
    exit();
}
```